# Converting column to date type changes year of original value

Tags: r, dataframe, types, dplyr, data-manipulation

I have a dataframe and I'm trying to change one of the columns from character values to date values. I was able to accomplish this, but the dates in the column are being changed--instead of keeping the original date of "01/28/2019" it'll change the year to "01/28/2020" in the output. How can I fix this to keep the original date?

This is the code I have:

```
###create enddate column
df["enddate"] <- NA
df$enddate[df$filenames %like% "filename1"] <- "01/28/2019"
df$enddate[df$filenames %like% "filename2"] <- "02/25/2019"
df$enddate[df$filenames %like% "filename3"] <- "03/26/2019"

###change enddate column from character to date type
df$enddate <- as.Date(x = df$enddate, format = "%m/%d/%y")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The isssue is `%y` instead of `%Y`.  The year is in 4 digit format and according to `?strptime` (where the documentation for formats are mentioned in detail)

> %y
>   Year without century (00–99). On input, values 00 to 68 are prefixed by 20 and 69 to 99 by 19 – that is the behaviour specified by the 2004 and 2008 POSIX standards, but they do also say ‘it is expected that in a future version the default century inferred from a 2-digit year will change’.
>
> %Y
>   Year with century. Note that whereas there was no zero in the original Gregorian calendar, ISO 8601:2004 defines it to be valid (interpreted as 1BC): see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0_(year). Note that the standards also say that years before 1582 in its calendar should only be used with agreement of the parties involved.

```
df$enddate <- as.Date(x = df$enddate, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
```

---

Also, instead of doing this separately an option is to do this once

```
keydat <- data.frame(filenames = paste0('filename', 1:3), enddate = c("01/28/2019", "02/25/2019", "03/26/2019"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
setDT(df)[keydat, endddate := mdy(enddate), on = .(filenames)]
```